# Generating a factor score for additional data using R and factanal

Tags: regression

Using this simple R code, I have performed a factor analysis on my dataset:

```
factanal(df, factors = 6, scores = "regression", rotation = "varimax")
```

I have now found significant factors that I want to keep. I also have chosen to generate scores using the "regression" argument. I'm still not clear on all the steps `factanal` uses to provide the scores, but after some digging, I found that the "regression" argument does use what is known as Thomson's regression to generate some score. That score then seems to be turned into a z-score given all the scores.

So here is the question:  Let's say that some new data comes in and I want to be able to give it a score as well. This new data happens to be one individual sample (the equivalent of one row of a new dataset).

Is there a proper way to give an individual sample a score or must the scores be generated on a population basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote the following function that takes the fit object returned by `factanal` and new data that you provide (e.g., a data frame or matrix with identical variable names), along with the original data.

```
score_new_data <- function(fit, new_data, original_data) {
    means <- sapply(original_data[,row.names(fit$correlation)], mean)
    sds <- sapply(original_data[,row.names(fit$correlation)], sd)
    z <- as.matrix(scale(new_data[,row.names(fit$correlation)], 
                         center = means,
                        scale = sds))
    z %*% solve(fit$correlation, fit$loadings)
}
```

So for example,

```
bfi <- na.omit(bfi)
variables <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4")
data <- bfi[,variables]
fit <- factanal(data, factors = 2, scores = "regression", rotation = "varimax")
```

This is a typical factor analysis.

And now supply some new data along with the fit of the factor analysis and the original data:

```
 score_new_data(fit, data[1:5, ], data)
```

And it generates the following:

```
> score_new_data(fit, data[1:5, ], data)
         Factor1    Factor2
61623  1.4937101  0.1714941
61629 -0.8927227 -1.7240081
61634 -0.4091523 -0.1982590
61640  0.4855813 -1.1968676
61661 -1.2631737  0.6817574
```

The answer here provides additional details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146131/180892

If you look at the code for `factanal` you can also learn more about what the regression method of scoring involves:

```
  Lambda <- fit$loadings # lambda are the loadings
  zz <- scale(z, TRUE, TRUE) # matrix of data is z standardized
  # cv is correlation matrix
  sc <- zz %*% solve(cv, Lambda)
```

Comment: Beautiful! I get it now. Thanks again Jeromy!

Comment: I just adjusted the function so that it uses the means and sds of the original data for standardizing the new data.